# Grab & Move An Element From The Centre

Tags: javascript, svg, drag-and-drop, viewbox

I wonder what I am doing wrong with the following code.

The SVG has been zoomed in and translated, the element is dragging vertically fine, however, hortizontally it is going crazy.

https://jsbin.com/gahoseneyu/edit?js,output

```
const svg = document.getElementsByTagName( "svg" )[ 0 ];
const w = svg.getAttribute( "width" );
const h = svg.getAttribute( "height" );
const cry = document.getElementById( "cry" );
const reg = /\d*\.\d[^\s]/g;
const viewBox = svg.getAttribute( "viewBox" ).match( reg );
const wRatio = w / viewBox[ 2 ];
const hRatio = h / viewBox[ 3 ];
console.log( "viewbox is...", viewBox, wRatio, hRatio );
cry.addEventListener( "mousedown", function(){
    this.addEventListener( "mousemove", function( e ){
        let newX = (e.pageX / wRatio) + parseFloat( viewBox[ 0 ]) - 22,
             newY = (e.pageY / hRatio) + parseFloat( viewBox[ 1 ]) - 22;
        this.setAttribute( "transform", `translate(${ newX },${ newY })`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the viewBox is not the same as the viewport, which is what is actually used. For example, your viewBox starts at 191 units along, and yet you can see your cry element which is has an x coordinate of 0. It helps if you add a rect to view the viewport:

`<rect x="191.37" y="15.73" width="212.59" height="393.23"/>`

You can use the `preserveAspectRatio` to preserve the aspect ratio depend on what you're trying to do (This tutorial should help: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html)

Alternatively you can calculate what the true viewBox is:

```
const svg = document.getElementsByTagName( "svg" )[ 0 ];
const cry = document.getElementById( "cry" );
const h = svg.clientHeight;
const w = svg.clientWidth;

const viewBoxW = svg.viewBox.baseVal.width;
const viewBoxH = svg.viewBox.baseVal.height;
let wRatio = w / viewBoxW;
let hRatio = h / svg.viewBoxH;
let viewBoxX = svg.viewBox.baseVal.x;
let viewBoxY = svg.viewBox.baseVal.y;

if (wRatio > hRatio) {
    wRatio = hRatio;
    viewBoxX = w / 2 / wRatio - (viewBoxX + viewBoxW / 2);
} else {
    hRatio = wRatio;
    viewBoxY = h / 2 / hRatio - (viewBoxY + viewBoxH / 2);
}


svg.addEventListener( "mousedown", function(){
    this.addEventListener( "mousemove", function( e ){

        let newX = e.pageX / wRatio - viewBoxX - 22,
            newY = e.pageY / hRatio + viewBoxY - 22;

        cry.setAttribute( "transform", `translate(${ newX },${ newY })`);
    });
});
```

Note that you should add the transform to the `cry` element.

Also, when you first click on the element, say on its corner, it will jump so the mouse is on the center. To avoid this you need to calculate the original offset between the click and the object center and use this instead of (-22, -22).

Comment: Thank you Peter. Im going back at the reviewing the scaleIn function to fix the aspect ration, then hopefully it should work. Wonderful code with a few pointers for me to adopt. Thanks again.